# Relaxed Bin Packing Problem

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, packing

The problem I have is like this bin packing problem, but instead I have $n$ bins and a collection of items with discrete masses. I need to put at least $m$ kg of stuff in each bin.

Is there an efficient way of doing this? Is there a way that will assure there is approximately the same amount in each bin? Does having a good guess at the probability distribution of the masses help?

**More explicitly:**

I have $q$ objects $\{o_1...o_q\}$, each has a size $w(o_i) \in \mathbb{N}$.

I need to find a collection of $n$ disjoint bins $B = \{b_1...b_n\}$ containing the objects such that

$$\forall b_i \in B: \sum_{o \in b_i}w(o) > m$$

for some $m$. When it is possible that is.

Comment: What is your measure?  If you can put exactly (or at least) $m$ kg of stuff in each bin?  Can you write the problem definition formally?  Are you familiar with the [Multiple Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem) (which admits a PTAS)?

Comment: I assume you mean Measure of efficiency - I guess what is most important is an expected run time? I will write it more formally.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is NP-complete because it is in NP and captures the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with $n = 2$ and $m = \frac12 \sum_{i = 1}^q{w(o_i)} - \frac12 \min_{i}w(o_i)$. If an equal weight partition exists, then the items can be packed in two bins each of weight $\frac12 \sum_{i = 1}^q{w(o_i)}>m$. If it doesn't, then one of the two bins would have weight at most $m$.

Comment: Its my first time with this subject! SO getting stuck at various things. You know of any resource to see a lot of such reductions? Its seems quite queer as to how people come up with these!

Comment: The general advice is "look for similar-sounding problems". This was a very simple case in which the problem is a more general version of a known hard problem, so no real transformation was required. Check the reference questions http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/in-basic-terms-what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other, and any algorithms textbook, e.g. Chapter 8 here: http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf

Comment: @user6818 You may be interested in [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) and [browsing the site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory+reductions). Also, Garey/Johnson!